# Session Variable fails when generated through IMG tag

Tags: php, session-variables

I have a captcha that generates dice images and a session variable.  It fails randomly on the live server but never does on the development box.  I'm not sure if its a problem with the session variables or something with the header() called below.  Maybe some combination of the two?

Near the top of the main index page there is a `session_start();`.  The form page is loaded midway the index through an include().

In the form, the captcha is loaded through this line:

```
<img src="generatedice.php" alt="captcha" height="50px"/>
```

The script `generatedice.php` generates the random numbers and displays the pngs of dice.  Then creates session a session variable.

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {  
    session_start();
}
    $_SESSION['total']=md5(SECRET+$total);

    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($img);
    imagedestroy($img);
```

In the form's POST file the variable is checked via this:

```
if (md5(SECRET+$_REQUEST['answer'])==$_SESSION['total']) {
```

When I echo the two variables inside the POST file they are usually different.

```
eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3 VS a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c
```

So is the hosting company handling session headers differently somehow?  I'm a tad bit puzzled and would love to know what to check.

Edit:
I think this might be a session page-load related issue.  The image is rendered after the index page if I am right.  So they end up being different sessions maybe?  How can I fix though?

Edit 2:
This also might be relevant.  Its the code at the start of the main index.

```
ob_start(); 
header('Cache-Control: max-age=604800');
session_start();

// Regenerate the Session for Security
if (!isset($_SESSION['regen'])) 
{ 
   session_regenerate_id(); 
   $_SESSION['regen'] = true; 
}
```

Edit 3:

For the record, I have completely removed this captcha process and replaced it.  But I'm still curious about how it could have been fixed.

Comment: Have you compared `SECRET + $_REQUEST['answer']`  to `SECRET + $total`?  (Not the MD5 hashes, but the actual strings themselves)

Comment: Yes, they are don't match either.  The form number is correct but the generated one is wrong somehow.

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the conditional wrapped around `session_start()`?  (I ask because generally I see implementations in which `session_start()` is called every time, even when the session was started in another request; in that case, the session would merely be resumed.)

Comment: You also use `session_start()` in the file that processes the POST, right?  And have you checked the actual session total to see what it says?  (This might be made easier with more complete code, as there are a lot of unknowns.)

Comment: @Maelish, hey dude. Did you manage to solve this issue?  I would like to know since am facing the same problem.

Comment: @KAD  I honestly can't recall.  It has been more than a year.  Sorry!

Comment: oh damn what a luck!! Thanks anyway dude

Answer (score 1):

I think the actual problem is that the image generated is "cached" by the browser. So it will be reused from cache and the Session variable is NEVER set (or remains at its first state), cause the script is never invoked, even when the image is displayed to the user.

Try to generate the img-tag using PHP and append a random parameter to ensure the client browser is calling the scriptfile again and therefore your session variable is refreshed on every request.

```
echo '<img src="generatedice.php?r='.time().'" alt="captcha" height="50px"/>';
```

This will avoid that the browser caches the image, cause the url will be different from second to second.

---

If you are including the image on the same page you are trying to process the answer, it might also be possible, that you are actually updating the session to the NEW Captcha, before you check on the first one.

Try to exclude the image, if an answer has been given to see if that is the case:

```
  if (!isset($_REQUEST["answer"])){
     echo '<img src="generatedice.php?r='.time().'" alt="captcha" height="50px"/>';
   }else{
     if (md5(SECRET+$_REQUEST['answer'])==$_SESSION['total']) { 
       echo "Your answer was correct";
     }else{
       echo "Your answer was wrong";
     }
   }
```

Comment: I've tried both of those with no luck.  :-(  Would I have the same problem if I turned the `generatedice.php` file into a function instead?